# pass File between components in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to pass a file to a second component with angular

```
this.router.navigate(['/secondComponent'], { queryParams: { file: File}})
```

Or pass it via formData

```
 var formData: any = new FormData();
 formData.append("file", file);
 this.router.navigate(['/secondComponent'], { queryParams: { file: File}})
```

It doesn't work like this. How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a few options here. Passing the entire `File` object via query params won't work. I guess technically, it could work if you were to pass the entire file body as a string argument in the URL, but I wouldn't recommend that.

What you can do:

- Use local storage
- Use a Singleton Service for storage purposes
- Pass the `File` object in the navigation extras

To stick with your current setup, I would recommend going with the 3rd option and do something like this:

`this.router.navigate(['/some-route'], {state: {data: myFile}});`

https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: Do you have any tutorial for the third option. I am a beginner. Or can you give an example of code?

Comment: For passing the file via navigation extras? Yea, the code snippet is pasted in the answer. You should be able to use that instead of your current method. To get the value, you'll have to pull in the activated route and take a look at what's imported.

Comment: I would appreciate your help

Comment: If you can reproduce your current code in stackblitz, I can show you how to do it with navigation extras

Answer (score 1):

If you want a proper async navigation between angular route components then you should consider using `rxjs` library which is provided by angular natively. You can follow the following steps to achieve that:

1. Create a new service with a preferred name.
2. Create a new `Subject` in the service and subscribe it in your component that is routed.
3. Emit your file object as a value in the subject before routing.

Answer (score -1):

you might want to consider passing the file id, or file name through the router and then reloading the file once you have routed.

The thing you have to keep in mind, is it's possible for a user to hit the browser refresh button, in which case you need to generate the entire page and all its contents based on the url.

Comment: Can you tell me how? I am a beginner and I'm confused. Thanks

Comment: presumable you are loading the file in the first page. can you do it the same on the second? Or if its user generated file, you need to save the file somewhere, and then load it in the second routed page.